# C++ why my template expansion lead to compiler stack overflow?

Tags: c++, templates, meta, expand

I was trying template meta programming and writing a function to calculate power of base^re like 3^2=9

```
template<int N>
int Tpow(int base){return N==0?1:base*Tpow<N-1>(base);}
int main()
{
    int r3=Tpow<3>(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Just several lines, but it crashes both gcc and clang. Where did I get wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Marked as duplicate. Even though the other question involves `constexpr` and this doesn't, the underlying misunderstanding is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** You have to specialize your template for N equal 0. Like:

```
template<>
int Tpow<0>(int base){return 1;}
```

Now that you have this, you could also optimize your original template like so:

```
template<int N>
int Tpow(int base){return base*Tpow<N-1>(base);}
```

because you know you handle the case of N equal 0.

**Explanation:** Your compiler is basically doing this: It sees

```
int r3=Tpow<3>(2);
```

and makes a function for 3 as the template variable, like so

```
int Tpow_3(int base){return 3==0?1:base*Tpow<3-1>(base);}
```

and then it needs to make a function for 2 as template variable, like so

```
int Tpow_2(int base){return 2==0?1:base*Tpow<2-1>(base);}
```

and this goes on and on an on, because the compiler doesn't care about your `0==0?...` yet.

Comment: and `int` should be changed to `unsigned int`

Answer (score 1):

The compiler must compile the entire function body: it cannot rely on the ternary conditional to only compile one side. So there is no block on the recursion.

(Using the `constexpr` of C++11 will not help either).

To solve this, you need to *specialise* the function for the N = 0 case.

Comment: However, `if constexpr` of C++17 should help.